# How can I stop evolution from trying to connect to google?

Tags: evolution, google

I'm only using Evolution for my calendar with EteSync but it keeps trying to connect to google which is very annoying. Does anyone know how to stop it from trying to connect to google?

Thanks

Comment: What service provides your calendar?

Comment: As my post stated I'm using EteSync for calendar as well as contacts